# Pulling SQLite database from Android 4.3

Tags: android, adb

I'm running the newest version of Android on the new Nexus 7. I'm developing an app that uses SQLite database to store data, and I'd like to view this on my computer.

I can't run `adb -d shell` followed by `run-as my.package.name`, I'll get a permission denied error. I can't either run adb as root: `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`. If I try to use `adb pull /data/data/package/databases/database > C:/Users/Me/Desktop/database.sqlite`, I'll also get a permission denied error.

Any workarounds? I don't want to root the device.

Comment: And some test code to your app to copy the DB to the sdcard e.g. a button on the main layout - "Copy Database"

Answer (score 4):

Go to adb shell then

```
run-as my.package.name cat /data/data/package/databases/database >/sdcard/db

adb pull /sdcard/db
```

Comment: This should work but make sure to have android:debuggable="true" on your manifest inside the application tag.

Comment: `run-as: Package 'my.package' is unknown`. Yes, I changed `my.package` to the right one.

Comment: @CarlosPaulino I think debuggable is set to true by default if you leave it out of your manifest

Comment: On Android 4.3 real device, after i ran the "run-as" command I lost access to /sdcard/db. So using cat I did a copy of the databse and set 777 permisions to it with chmod. I exited from run-as, and then I was able to run cat the new copy of the database to the /sdcard.

Comment: It doesn't work in Android 4.4.2.  run-as: Package 'mypackage' is unknown.